# org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl incompatible with org.dom4j.Document

Tags: java, document, xerces

Im reading some RSS from an URL and are experiencing some troubles.
Initially I had a straightforward implementation like this:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document doc = reader.read(new URL(sURL));
```

However, this didnt allow me to timeout the request if the response was very slow. So I changed it to :

```
public static org.dom4j.Document readXml(InputStream is) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        dbf.setValidating(false);
        dbf.setIgnoringComments(false);
        dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        return (org.dom4j.Document)db.parse(is);
    }

     SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

    URL myUrl = new URL(sURL);
    URLConnection c = myUrl.openConnection();
    c.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    c.setReadTimeout(10000);
    org.dom4j.Document doc = readXml(c.getInputStream());
    Element root = doc.getRootElement();
```

When trying this, I get a annyoing error:

```
org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl incompatible with org.dom4j.Document
```

How can I avoid this? None of the above methods are supposed to return that type of Document, and I also try to cast to the correct document type..

EDIT: The problem is db.parse(is) which returns org.w3c.dom ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

By using :

```
DOMReader domReader = new DOMReader();
org.dom4j.Document dom4jDoc = domReader.read(doc);
org.dom4j.Element root = (Element)dom4jDoc.getRootElement();
```

To create an `org.dom4j.Document` from the `org.w3c.dom.Document`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your `Element` is of type `org.dom4j.Element` and not `org.w3c.dom`, `javax.bind.xml`, etc.

In other words, dom4j API is not compatible with Java's built-in XML API. The two simply do not mix together, unless you operate with Strings (e.g. generate XML in dom4j and parse it with Java's XML or vice versa).

Comment: The problem is the db.parse() method. It returns an object of type org.w3c.dom